# How to create a function in javascript that averages the value of first 3 indices for 400 arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Hey I need to create a function that converts a received RGB array into greyscale by averaging the rgb values. However, there are 400 rgb arrays that need to be averaged. I am not sure where to start as i am a beginner in javascript. Any help will be appreciated.
For example, one of the RGB arrays will look something like: RGBA1 = [R1, G1, B1, A1). A is alpha value and needs to be ignored in this case.

Comment: You need to give an example of the array and your expected output.

Comment: are the colors different weighted?

Answer (score 1):

Average method for RGB to Greyscale works by formula.

Gr = (R + G +B)/3

To compute greyscale values of your entire dataset, you have to use cycle.
Quick idea how to do this is as follows.

```js
var rgbaArrays = [
  [11, 22, 33, 10],
  [77, 88, 99, 15],
  [5, 10, 254, 20],
];



function computeGreyscale(rgbaArrays) {
  var greyScale = [];
  for (i = 0; i < rgbaArrays.length; i++) {
    greyScale[i] = (rgbaArrays[i][0] + rgbaArrays[i][1] + rgbaArrays[i][2]) / 3
  }
  return greyScale;
}

console.log(computeGreyscale(rgbaArrays));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .reduce and then divide by array length to find the average:

```js
const RGBArrays = [
  [11, 22, 33],
  [77, 88, 99],
  [5, 10, 254],
];
const { rSum, gSum, bSum } =
  RGBArrays.reduce((
  { rSum = 0, gSum = 0, bSum = 0},
  [thisR, thisG, thisB]) => {

  rSum += thisR;
  gSum += thisG;
  bSum += thisB;
  return { rSum, gSum, bSum };
}, {});
console.log(rSum / RGBArrays.length);
console.log(gSum / RGBArrays.length);
console.log(bSum / RGBArrays.length);
```

Comment: Don't you think `reduce` is a little overkill for this? I mean he said he was a beginner so it only seems right that you present him with a solution comprised of building blocks he is familiar with. It'll be a rather unfortunate conclusion if he ended up copying and pasting your code instead of understanding it and making it "his".